# Sparkler (aka Spark-Crawler) Guide?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

**Sparkler:** Sparkler (aka Spark-Crawler) is an evolution of Apache Nutch to run on Apache Spark

Is there any other guide other than this [Sparkler version 0.1](https://github.com/USCDataScience/sparkler/wiki/sparkler-0.1) like how to connect hdfs with sparkler. I already studied this but couldn't find anything regarding this. It is not explaining a lots of things. So if any body know how to connect hdfs with sparkler or any other guide, please do share thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that you have to write your own helper for this